# How do I copy values from 2 dimensional array into new column in pandas dataframe

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe, copy

I want to do something like this, where df.index matches 2dim_arr exactly

```
df['newcol']=2dim_arr[df.index][df.existingcol.values]
```

I can get at the values I want if I do this:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
  print(2dim_arr[i][df.iloc[i].existingcol])
```

Thanks in advance for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically using the values from `existingcol` as column indices and going through each row of the `2D` array to select one element per row off the `2D` array. Thus, we can use [`NumPy's integer array indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) to achieve the desired new column -

```
col_idx = df.existingcol.values
df['newcol'] = dim2_arr[np.arange(len(dim2_arr)), col_idx]
```

Sample run -

1) Inputs :

```
In [311]: df
Out[311]: 
   existingcol
0            2
1            0
2            0
3            1
4            0
5            2
6            1
7            4
8            3
9            3

In [313]: dim2_arr
Out[313]: 
array([[25, 75, 70, 45, 67],
       [21, 85, 74, 68, 61],
       [79, 33, 22, 77, 25],
       [69, 31, 67, 11, 45],
       [50, 12, 35, 55, 89],
       [62, 59, 86, 55, 58],
       [67, 41, 77, 88, 79],
       [64, 30, 36, 25, 21],
       [24, 73, 68, 84, 79],
       [50, 53, 55, 71, 84]])
```

2) Use proposed codes :

```
In [314]: col_idx = df.existingcol.values

In [317]: df['newcol'] = dim2_arr[np.arange(len(dim2_arr)), col_idx]

In [318]: df
Out[318]: 
   existingcol  newcol
0            2      70
1            0      21
2            0      79
3            1      31
4            0      50
5            2      86
6            1      41
7            4      21
8            3      84
9            3      71
```

Comment: Fantastic answer Divakar. This worked perfectly! Thanks so much!

Comment: @DeanaH. If this solved your question, consider accepting it by clicking on the hollow tick next to the solution, More info here - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work